# Is every orthogonal set in an inner product space is an orthonormal set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is every orthogonal set in an inner product space  is  an orthonormal set ?

My attempts   : My answer is yes .

let V  be an inner product space now take $S= \{v_1,v_2,.......,v_k\}$ is  an  orthogonal set in V then $\{\frac{v_1}{||v_1||},\frac{v_2}{||v_2||},.....,\frac{v_k}{||v_k||}\}$  is  an orthonormal set in $V$.

Pliz verified

thanks u

Comment: The body of your question indicates something other than the title, which has the obvious counterexample $\{(2,0),(0,2)\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard dot product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every orthogonal set is not a orthonormal set as $v$ and $\frac{v}{||v||}$ can be different vectors of vector space.

What we can say is,

Every orthogonal set (with non-zero vectors) can be converted into orthonormal set by normalizing each vector in the set.